# Securing my PowerShell Scripts

Tags: powershell

I've come into a situation whereby I am essentially providing custom scripts (bespoke) for customers who require them, which are written in PowerShell. They are purely DevOps related.

It's got to a stage whereby there is enough "business" interest that I need to, in some way (whether completely, or at least to some degree) prevent people from seeing the raw code.

The first thing that came to mind was to simply convert the scripts in some form into an executable file. Realistically I appreciate there is no way to completely prevent people from reverse engineering anything, but essentially any method to at least make accessing the code more of an effort.

Comment: File permissions are your friend.

Comment: How when I am distributing these scripts outside a single environment ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some ideas here:

https://github.com/danielbohannon/Invoke-Obfuscation

Invoke-Obfuscation is a PowerShell v2.0+ compatible PowerShell command and script obfuscator.